# How do I add "mobile app install" header on website?

Tags: ios, html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, safari

I'm looking to add a header to my website similar to the one seen on paypal.com on mobile devices:

[Paypal Mobile Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Ehf.jpg)

I've seen it on many other sites as well.  How do I do this?  Does it only work for Safari?

I would like it to be on my mobile site as well, http://getderby.co

Thanks

Comment: can you please clarify your question? Do you want the div containing the derby logo and the login button to be fixed while scroll? or a transparent bg? Or enable deeplinking so that if you have a related app it will prompt to open with it.?

Comment: You're right, my question was unclear.  I want to enable deeplinking so my related app (ios/android) will prompt to install/open.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer:

Implementing a Smart App Banner on Your Website

This only works on iOS, so I'm not sure about Android at the moment.